# How to use different marker colors in a single probplot using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am using the probplot command in Matlab to obtain the probability plot of a a single dataset . There are 15 data points ( all numbers), I would like to use different markercolors for different data point within a single probplot.

I tried to initialize a cell of character arrays with different colors and used in the following code but didn't work

```
data =[68391;54744;54682;71629;42610;54371;37500;41222;39767;65042;54706;15108;57000;55460;73360]';

colorarray = cell(1,15);
facecolorarray=cell(1,15);
markertypearray = cell(1,15);

GBIds =  false(1,15);
reqd_IDxs = [2 3 5 6 8];

GBIds(reqd_IDxs)=1;
colorarray(GBIds)={'b'};
facecolorarray(GBIds)={'b'};
markertypearray(GBIds)={'o'};

colorarray(~GBIds)={'k'};
facecolorarray(~GBIds)={'r'};
markertypearray(~GBIds)={'+'};


h1=probplot('lognormal',data,'noref');
set(h1(1),'marker',markertypearray,'color',colorarray,'linewidth',3,'markersize',25,'markerfacecolor',facecolorarray);
```

Error :

Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Line/set
Error setting property 'Marker' of class 'Line':
Invalid enum value. Use one of these values: '+' | 'o' | '*' | '.' | 'x' | 'square' | 'diamond' | 'v' | '^' | '>' | '<' | 'pentagram' |
'hexagram' | 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may not be able to pass a marker array at once and have to pass individual markers. For example, use

```
set(h1(1),'marker',markertypearray{1},'color',colorarray{1},'linewidth',3,...
'markersize',25,'markerfacecolor',facecolorarray{1});
```

In order to use different markers, you may need to plot each set of points with the same marker one at a time with `hold on`, inside a `for` loop, something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/406017-how-can-i-create-a-vector-of-markers-for-a-scatter-plot).

Comment: Thanks. 

I can extract the Y data using h1.ydata, but I dont know how to retain the y axis scale ( probability %). If I can do this, then I could use the plot function

Comment: Add `ylim([0, 1])` after plotting.

Comment: Thanks. but the y data doesn't come in probability %. it comes in quantiles, something in  a range of -1.5 to 1.5 . I don't know hot to convert quantiles to probability.

Comment: This seems beyond the scope of this question, so I suggest starting a new question with your current code and the error. However, note that for the solution to work, you can continue using `probplot` multiple times with different data points and don't have to change to using `plot`.